# Proof for a triple composition chain rule

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule, function-and-relation-composition

Assuming that $f,g,h$ are all differentiable throughout $\mathbb{R}$, what is the chain rule for $(h \circ g \circ f) (x)$ and the proof for it?

I know that first $(g \circ f)'(x) = g'(f(x))f'(x)$. Is it just applying this rule twice? Then how would one state a proof for such a formula?

Comment: Hint: you are right, just apply the chain rule for two functions as many times as you need (twice should do). All the proof you need is to make it clear how you applied the chain rule for two functions to get your answer.

Comment: There's no need for such a proof: just apply the chain rule to $\bigl(h\circ(g\circ f)\bigr)'$, and apply it again to $(g\circ f)'$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use associativity:

$$
(h \circ g \circ f)'(x)=(h \circ (g  \circ f))'(x)=h'((g \circ f)(x))\cdot (g\circ f)'(x)
$$
Now $(g \circ f)'(x)=g'(f(x))\cdot f'(x)$ and therefore
$$
(h \circ g \circ f)'(x)=h'((g \circ f)(x))\cdot g'(f(x))\cdot f'(x)
$$

Comment: You will get the same answer here if you read $h \circ g \circ f$ as $(h \circ g) \circ f$. Associativity is what allows us to abuse notation and write $h \circ g \circ f$ without any brackets.

Comment: @RobArthan indeed, I just wrote the way I though could be easiest to understand to the OP